# How to set value in dropdownboxlist in Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I am developing web application in `angularjs`. I have one html form inside that i have dropdownboxlist. I have two scenarios here. First I am binding values to dropdown as below.

```
<select ng-model="user.Nationality" 
         name="nationality" 
         id="Nationality" 
         ng-options="user.Nationality for user in nationalityList" 
         required>
     <option value="" label="Nationality">Nationality</option>
</select>
```

Second scenario is on page load previously selected data i want to bind if exists. If for some use already data for nationality for example if the user has selected nationality as India previously then on page load i want to bind only India to Dropdown.
Below is my object receiving in api call.

```
"NationalitObj":
 {  
        "ID":1,
        "Nationality":"indian"
},
```

Now i want to set Nationality as india for the above dropdoownboxlist.

Below is the code how i am trying to set value for nationality.

```
 $scope.nationalityList = PersonalInfo.NationalitObj;
 $scope.user.Nationality = $scope.nationalityList.Nationality;
```

This leads to error Cannot set property 'Nationality' of undefined. May i know how can i do this? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Before use this  $scope.user.Nationality, declare like $scope.user = [];

Comment: look into promises, if you wanr second to be executed after first. $q.when can be your solution

Comment: Thanks. Doesnt work out.

Comment: i tried this way also and doesnt work out.    $scope.nationalityList = [{ "ID": 1, "Nationality": "indian" }, { "ID": 2, "Nationality": "england" }];
                $scope.user.Nationality = $scope.nationalityList[1];

Comment: $scope.user.Nationality = $scope.nationalityList[1].Nationality try this.

Comment: Thanks. This is working but selected value should be value i received from api rather than Nationality. Should i use ng selected?

Comment: may i see you code from where you get object from api?

Comment: I have hard coded now rather than getting from api.    $scope.nationalityList = [{ "ID": 1, "Nationality": "indian" }];
                $scope.user.Nationality = $scope.nationalityList[0].Nationality; and still it wont work.

Comment: ng-options="user.ID as user.Nationality for user in nationalityList"  and try this in controller : $scope.user.Nationality = $scope.nationalityList[0].ID

Comment: $scope.user.Nationality = $scope.nationalityList[0].ID; this line gives me error cannot set property nationalty.

Comment: I missed this.       $scope.user = []; Now working. Please post your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer this :

```js
angular.module("app",[])
  .controller("ctrl",['$scope',function($scope){
    $scope.nationalityList = [
      {Id:1, Nationality:'Indian'},
      {id:2, Nationality:'American'}
    ]    
    $scope.user = {};
    $scope.user.Nationality =  $scope.nationalityList[0].Id;
  }])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
<select ng-model="user.Nationality" 
         name="nationality" 
         id="Nationality" 
         ng-options="user.Id as user.Nationality for user in nationalityList" 
         required>
     <option value="" label="Nationality">Nationality</option>
</select>
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: If the api returns "NationalitObj":{"ID":1,"Nationality":"indian"} then what should i change in the above code?

Comment: $scope.user.Nationality =  $scope.NationalitObj.Id; assign like this

Comment: $scope.user = {};
  $scope.user.Nationality = PersonalInfo.NationalitObj.ID; This should work right?

Comment: Yes but PersonalInfo should contain NationalitObj and aslo this line should be after the api call resolved.

Comment: function fillpersonaldetails(PersonalInfo)
            {  $scope.user = {};
                $scope.user.Nationality = PersonalInfo.NationalitObj.ID;} This is not giving me error but not binding values also.

Comment: Do you debug what is value inside personalInfo?

Comment: yeah. {"PersonalInfo":{"LoginId":2,"ID":1,"ROLSPOpportunityActivityID":6,"Nationality":0,"NationalitObj":{"ID":1,"Nationality":"indian"},"IDType":0,"IDTypeobj":{"ID":1,"IDType":"passport"}, still continues.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145410/discussion-between-jenny-and-niranjan-godbole).